# How to update specific element in a list in Elm

Tags: elm

There are couple `apples` ( in type of `List` ) which will expose themselvies in the web view. User can update any `size` attribute of an `Apple`. I have a msg type `UpdateSize` which will be triggered via `onInput`.

Editing any of the apples will only just trigger the message without knowing *which* apple to be updated.

Is that possible to pass an `id` attribute to `UpdateSize` message?

Thank you for reading this, Elm is great !

```
module Main exposing (main)

import Browser
import Html exposing (Html, button, div, text, input)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (onClick,onInput)
import String

type alias Apple = {
   size: Int}

type alias Model = {
    apples: List(Apple)}


initialModel : Model
initialModel =
    { apples = [ Apple 10, Apple 11, Apple 12] }


type Msg
    = UpdateSize String


update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
    case msg of
        UpdateSize s -> {model | apples = ??? } -- how to update a single Apple with new size
        _ -> model

viewApple : Apple -> Html Msg
viewApple a =
    input [ type_ "text" ,placeholder ""
          , value (String.fromInt a.size)
          , onInput UpdateSize]
          []



view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        (List.map viewApple model.apples)


main : Program () Model Msg
main =
    Browser.sandbox
        { init = initialModel
        , view = view
        , update = update
        }
```

Code link: https://ellie-app.com/ghd9jrcjKQQa1

Comment: Please put all relevant code in the question itself. A link to ellie is great, but it should be supplemental. Questions should be self-contained, so that they keep making sense even when external resources are taken down.

Comment: As for your question, how do you know which apple is which? What is the property, or set of properties, that determines that _this_ apple is not the same as _that_ apple?

Comment: @glennsl thanks. I use apple as a demo , I use size just a demo, but it can be replaced by `name` of the apple as well, which should be unique.

Comment: I figured as much, and my point is that by removing the properties you are also removing the ways you could identify the specific item you want to update. You could just use the list index, of course, but in the real world that's usually a flawed assumption that won't hold up. For example, if you were to sort or filter the items in the view the indexes would be wrong, and you would only be able to tell by observing unexpected behavior. Using a `name` property would be prone to duplicates unless uniqueness of names are ensured elsewhere, etc. Point is: the data matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current implementation it's not possible to know which apple to update since there's no unique attribute about the apples. What if two apples have the same size? If would be better if apples had IDs, or you used a dictionary type to keep track of the apples.

However, for the sake of demonstration, you could say that the list indeces of the apples are unique and you find them accordingly. In real life this will be a fragile solution.

Here's a naive approach using some helper functions from [`List.Extra`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/list-extra/latest/List-Extra).

```
-- ...

type alias Size =
    Int


type Msg
    = UpdateSize Int String


update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
    case msg of
        UpdateSize index sizeStr ->
            let
                maybeSize =
                    String.toInt sizeStr
            in
            maybeSize
                |> Maybe.withDefault (\size -> { model | apples = updateApple index size model.apples })
                |> model

        _ ->
            model


updateApple : Int -> Size -> List Apple -> List Apple
updateApple index size apples =
    let
        maybeApple =
            List.Extra.getAt index apples
    in
    maybeApple
        |> Maybe.map (\apple -> List.Extra.setAt index { apple | size = size } apples)
        |> Maybe.withDefault apples

-- ...

viewApple : Int -> Apple -> Html Msg
viewApple index a =
    input
        [ type_ "text"
        , placeholder ""
        , value (String.fromInt a.size)
        , onInput (UpdateSize index)
        ]
        []


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        (List.indexedMap viewApple model.apples)
```